# Convert Wget call to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wget

I am trying to convert a wget invoke call by using the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet, but the code i tried leads to an issue.

```
wget --no-check-certificate -S -q --header "Accept: application/json" --header='ContentType: application/json' --header="Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -O https://10.107.174.117/itfm-cloud/rest/reports-api/export-csv?name=servers
```

This is what i tried with Invoke-WebRequest, but leads to an error.

```
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = @("Tls12","Tls11","Tls","Ssl3")


$username = "ebc\cloudadmin"
$password = "are1!" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)


Invoke-WebRequest https://10.107.174.117/itfm-cloud/rest/reports-api/export-csv?name=servers -Credential $cred
```

[image]

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

In the wget request, you authenticate with a bearer token in the `Authorization` header - do the same with PowerShell:

```
$headers = @{
    Accept = 'application/json' 
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Authorization = 'Bearer <TOKEN>'
}
Invoke-WebRequest https://10.107.174.117/itfm-cloud/rest/reports-api/export-csv?name=servers -Headers $headers
```